# Sign In With Google HTML API Sign In + Sign Up buttons on the same page

Tags: api, google-signin

I have an HTML modal with a "Sign In" and a "Sign Up" tab.  Each tab offer users the ability to "Sign In" or "Sign Up" with Google.

[Google's reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference) states that I should only include the `g_id_onload` in one element per page.  Google treats either context: 'signin' vs 'signup' the same in the backend. Is there a way to capture which `g_id_signin` button was clicked if I have multiple buttons on the page, so I can give the user proper feedback?

eg: "Thanks for signing up!", "Successfully signed in", "Account does not exist. Please sign up first."

Answer (score 1):

A hacky work around: while [Google's reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference) shows it inside the `g_id_onload` container, you can also set the data-nonce attribute in the `g_id_signin` (button) container instead.  It appears to be one of few (if not the only) custom data-attributes you can provide and get back in the payload response.

For a given sign in button, set the data-nonce to 'signin' / 'signup' `data-nonce=[context]` Or if you have need for a proper nonce, come up with (2) distinct for each context.

On successful verify, the `nonce` attribute in the payload response will let you know which button the user clicked.